# error Illegal char <:> at index 42: com.em.app-mergeDebugResources-60:/values/values.xml, when implementation 'com.cometchat:chat-uikit-android:4.0.4'

Tags: debugging, merge, char, resources

Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource

[issue whenever building app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYioO.png)
Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file D:\download\one8ty\Bindaasgang\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 42: com.bindaasgang.app-mergeDebugResources-60:/values/values.xml